# Google Analytics shows visits to pages redirected in .htaccess

Tags: google-analytics, htaccess, mod-rewrite

Yesterday, I switched on a section of pages in our site that replaces a really old collection of pages.  In our .htaccess file, I have rules that redirect a request for any page in the old section to the equivalent in the new section.  All the tests I have done show this is working properly. I put the old URL into the address bar, and the new version of it is displayed.

However, when I look at Google Analytics Real-Time view, I am seeing a few page views for the old URLs. Since the redirect should occur before the GA code ever runs, does anyone have an idea about how GA is seeing visits for the old pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is mainly down to **caching.** Your pages may be served from a user's local browser cache, which will continue to log visits from old URLs. Other users may be viewing a cached version in Google, which also carries Google Analytics code.